# How to determine if a PR has all required codeowner approvals using GH REST API?

Tags: github, github-api, github-api-v3

I would like to use the GH REST API to determine if a particular PR has all required codeowner approvals.  Then, if the answer is yes, I would like to further determine the date and time at which the final approval occurred.

I have tried a bunch of things.

The documentation suggests that if all approvals have been granted, the `requested_reviewers` and `requested_teams` array will be empty.  This does not appear to be true though.  As a test, I created a PR that required reviews from 3 different teams.  Then I manually added a couple of additional people.  I reached to people from the 3 different teams and asked them to approve my PR.  After doing this, in the GH html webpage, it shows "Changes Approved" with a green checkmark.  But when I do the GH API request, the `requested_reviewers` and `requested_teams` arrays are not empty.

I then tried appending `/reviews` to the end of the request URL, to get all of the reviews.  They all show up as `APPROVED`, but nothing in the response indicates whether the review was a *required* review, or someone who was just passing by and felt like hitting approve.

It feels like the best way is to do the following steps:

1. Get the pull request object
2. Examine the `requested_teams` field (we don't use individual names in our CODEOWNERS)
3. Walk the list of reviews by querying the `/reviews` endpoint
4. For each one, query the user's teams and see if any of them match any of the teams in `requested_teams`.

This is a lot of work and pretty complicated, but it seems do-able in theory.  Is there a simpler way?

Comment: I'm also interested in this answer, even if it requires the GraphQL API instead of REST API